# Declaring strings as std:string in C++

Tags: c++, string, private-members

This is based on GCC/G++ and usually on Ubuntu.

Here's my sample program I've done:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string c = "Test";
    cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works fine.

But I have two issues that I don't quite get...

1. Writing the string declaration as `std:string` (with one `:`) also works fine. What's the difference?
2. If I use `std:string` (with one `:`) within a class to declare a private variable, I get an error **error: ‘std’ does not name a type**. Example of this declaration:

```
class KType
{
private:
    std:string N;
};
```

Can someone please explain these issues?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Writing the string declaration as std:string also works fine. What's the difference.

The difference would be slight clearer if you formatted it differently:

```
std:
    string c = "Test";
```

You're declaring a *label* called `std`, and using the name `string` which has been dumped into the global namespace by `using namespace std;`. Writing it correctly as `std::string`, you're using the name `string` from the `std` namespace.

> If I use this `std::string` within a class to declare a private variable, I get an error error: `‘std’ does not name a type.`

That's because you can't put a label in a class definition, only in a code block. You'll have to write it correctly as `std::string` there. (If the class is defined in a header, then `using namespace std` is an even worse idea than in a source file, so I urge you not to do that.)

Also, if you're using `std::string`, then you should `#include <string>`. It looks like your code works by accident due to `<iostream>` pulling in more definitions than it need to, but you can't portably rely on that.

Comment: That example of if I 'formatted it differently' is just beautiful. Thanks! Makes a lot of sense :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to include the string class header:

```
#include <string>
```

This code has a typo, missing a second colon

```
std:string N;
```

should be:

```
std::string N;
```

With a single colon, it becomes a label for goto, which is probably not what you meant.

Comment: @Matt-Petersson thanks for your inputs. I tried that but it was the same. And it DOES work in the first example. So I don't see why string in needed for the second :(

Comment: That wasn't a typo. Rather that's what I thought was correct as it worked before in the first example. But I see now that thre's a difference after `Mike-Seymour`'s explanation. Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 3):

**First problem:**

First of all, you are missing the `#include <string>` directive. You cannot rely on other headers (such as `<iostream>`) to `#include` the `<string>` header automatically. Apart from this:

**Second problem:**

> Writing the string declaration as std:string also works fine. What's the difference.

That is because you have an (evil) `using` directive at global namespace scope:

```
using namespace std;
```

The effect of this directive is that all names from the `std` namespace are imported into the global namespace. This is why the fully-qualified `std::string` and the unqualified `string` resolve to the same type.

If you omitted that `using namespace std;` directive, you would get a compiler error when using the unqualified `string` name.

**Third problem:**

> If I use this std::string within a class to declare a private variable, I get an error error: ‘std’ does not name a type. Example of this declaration:

You are missing a colon. That should be:

```
std::string
//  ^
```

And not

```
std:string
// ^
```

Comment: You said: `namespace are imported into the global namespace`. So why is this bad? Excuse me for my ignorance ;) And nice explanations +1

Comment: @itsols: Watch out, the quote is slightly different that what your excerpt seems to imply ;) It's the *names* from the `std` namespace that get imported into the global namespace. The reason why this is bad is that you could get name clashes between names that *belong* to the global namespace and names that are *imported* into the global namespace.

Answer (score 2):

> Writing the string declaration as std:string also works fine. What's the difference.

There is no difference, unless you declare something else called `string`. In your code, `string` and `std::string` refer to the same type. But avoid `using namespace std` at all cost.

> If I use this std::string within a class to declare a private variable, I get an error error: ‘std’ does not name a type. Example of this declaration:

You need to `#include <string>` in order to use `std::string`. What is happening is that in your first code sample, `<iostream>` seems to be including `<string>`. You cannot rely on that. You  must include `<string>`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour no worries. I think it is all sorted now.

Comment: @juanchopanza Nice one: `There is no difference, unless you declare something else called string`. And then there was light :) +1